# Copy GpuMat to CUDA Tensor

Tags: c++, opencv, cuda, pytorch

I am trying to run model inference in C++.
I succesfully traced model in Python with `torch.jit.trace`.
I am able to load model in C++ using `torch::jit::load()`.
I was able to perform inference both on cpu and gpu, however the starting point was always `torch::from_blob` method which seems to be creating cpu-side tensor.
For efficiency, I would like to cast/copy `cv::cuda::GpuMat` directly to CUDA Tensor. I have been digging through pytorch [tests](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/tree/master/test/cpp) and [docs](https://pytorch.org/cppdocs/) in search of convinient example, but was unable to find one.

Question:
How to create CUDA Tensor from cv::cuda::GpuMat?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
//define the deleter ...
void deleter(void* arg) {};

//your convert function 

cuda::GpuMat gImage;

//build or load your image here ...

std::vector<int64_t> sizes = {1, static_cast<int64_t>(gImage.channels()),
                          static_cast<int64_t>(gImage.rows),
                          static_cast<int64_t>(gImage.cols)};

long long step = gImage.step / sizeof(float);

std::vector<int64_t> strides = {1, 1, step, static_cast<int64_t>(gImage.channels())};

auto tensor_image = torch::from_blob(gImage.data, sizes, strides, deleter,  torch::kCUDA);
std::cout << "output tensor image : " << tensor_image << std::endl;
```

Comment: Thanks! I managed to run this code, with one problem. I think strides should be: {1, 1, step, channels}.

Comment: I've fixed the incorrect stride. see https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/19786